# How to set case-insensitive completion in a bash instance without Readline support

Tags: bash, shell, gnu, readline, bash-completion

I have a bash instance without Readline support, i.e. this bash is invoked with the `--noediting` option. The reason is that this bash instance is used by another program.

The other program wants to know how this bash would complete the command line and for this it issues `compgen` commands in the bash shell, e.g.

```
compgen -o default I
```

This works perfectly in my bash without Readline support. Here an example: Let's say, we are in a directory with three files:

```
IMG_1234.JPG
about.html
index.html
```

The command `compgen -o default I` prints duly

```
IMG_1234.JPG
```

However now I want to switch to case-insensitive completion. Normally I issue in the shell

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

and in a bash instance *with* Readline support everything is as expected: `compgen -o default I` prints

```
IMG_1234.JPG
index.html
```

However in my bash instance *without* Readline support the `bind` command does nothing and I still get only the `IMG_1234.JPG` match.

So, my question is: How can I set case-insensitive completion suggestions (when using `compgen`) in a bash instance which is invoked without Readline support?

Comment: Try configuring [/etc/inputrc](http://superuser.com/questions/90196/case-insensitive-tab-completion-in-bash)

Comment: My ~/.inputrc file contains `set completion-ignore-case on`, but a bash without Readline support seems to ignore this file.

Comment: `inputrc` is for `readline`.

Comment: @whjm Exactly! As the question clearly states I want to switch to case-insensitive completion suggestions via `compgen` in a "--noediting" bash (which does not use inputrc).

Answer (score 1):

## Test program:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "### CASE-SENSITIVE"
bash --noediting <<EOF
compgen -o default I
EOF
echo
echo "### CASE-FOLDING"
bash --noediting <<EOF
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
compgen -o default I
EOF
```

## Result:

```
### CASE-SENSITIVE
IMG_1234.JPG

### CASE-FOLDING
bash: line 1: bind: warning: line editing not enabled
IMG_1234.JPG
index.html
```

## Bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

If your bash version is different, then consider upgrading, as I can't reproduce your issue with 4.3.11.  (And you'll probably want to redirect stderr from the `bind` command; I left it in so you can see it's being executed).